# split tail of the vector and append head of same vector

Tags: coq

I want to prove `aaa` and we may need `ttt` to prove it.

I have no way to prove them.
Please tell me your solution.

```
Require Import Coq.Vectors.Vector.

Lemma ttt A n m (v:t A ((S n)+m)): append (fst (splitat 1 v)) (fst (splitat n (Vector.tl v))) = fst (splitat (S n) v).
Proof.
Admitted.

Lemma aaa A n m (v:t A ((S n)+m)): cons _ (Vector.hd v) n (fst (splitat n (Vector.tl v))) = fst (splitat (S n) v).
Proof.
rewrite -ttt.
remember (splitat n (Vtail v)).
Admitted.
```

Comment: `simpl; destruct splitat; reflexivity.` is sufficient to prove both `aaa` and `ttt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a non-empty vector `v : Vector.t A (S x)`, you can use `eta` to expose its constructor and hopefully make expressions reducible.

```
Lemma aaa A n m (v:t A ((S n)+m)): cons _ (Vector.hd v) n (fst (splitat n (Vector.tl v))) = fst (splitat (S n) v).
Proof.
  cbn in v. rewrite (eta v). cbn.
  destruct (splitat n _). cbn.
  reflexivity.
Qed.
```

The same proof script also works for `ttt`.